# How can I change the 'authentication options' in the 'application settings' to Federated Login

Tags: google-app-engine

I created a HRD application by choosing the Authentication Option as "Open to all Google Accounts users (default)", but now I need change that option to: "(Experimental) Federated Login" in order to open the app to all users with an OpenID Provider.

The problem is that the option box is disabled and I don't want delete and create the application again because I will lose the app Id.

How can I do it?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Coto

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can't.

> Warning:
>   Currently, you cannot switch authentication options for existing App Engine apps to or from Google Apps accounts for a domain. This option for restricting an application's authentication settings can only be set at app creation time.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth

Saying that, in my app the dropdown is available and selectable (application settings, authentication options). So not sure what is going on there.

Don't forget that you can buy a separate domain and point it towards whatever domain you end up using for you app and end users won't be able to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can freely switch between Google Accounts and Federated login, but you cannot change to or from Google Apps authentication post creation